# High CPU usage from while loop, checking for keypress event

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, asynchronous

I have a console application with two threads, one is doing repetitive time consuming work, the other is checking to see if the user has pressed the ESC key. If the ESC key was pressed, the time consuming work thread is paused, an "are you sure" message appears, and if yes is selected, the time consuming work thread finishes its current loop then exits.

The code I have to check for a key-press is using a lot of CPU resources due to the `while (!breakCurrentOperation(work)) ;` loop. How can I prevent this from happening?

Code:

```
    public void runTimeConsumingWork()
    {
        HardWork work = new HardWork();

        Thread workerThread = new Thread(() => work.StartWorking());
        workerThread.Start(); // Start the hard work thread

        while (!workerThread.IsAlive) ; // Hault untill Thread becomes Active 

        // Check if the user wants to stop the hard work
        while (!breakCurrentOperation(work)) ;

        // Cancle the hard work
        work.Stop();

        // Notify the User
        UserInterfaceController.WriteToConsole("Operation Cancled...");
    }


    public static bool breakCurrentOperation(HardWork work)
    {
        if (Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            var consoleKey = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (consoleKey.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                work.Pause(); // Pause
                UserInterfaceController.WriteToConsole("Do you want to stop the current process? \nType s to stop or c to continue.");
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input == "c" || input == "C")
                {
                    work.Pause(); // Unpause
                    return false; // Continue 
                }
                else if (input == "s" || input == "S")
                {
                    return true; // Break the loop
                }
                else
                {
                    UserInterfaceController.WriteToConsole("Error: Input was not recognized, the current process will now continue. Press Esc to stop the operation.");
                    work.Pause(); // Unpause
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

If I place a `Thread.Sleep(2000)` in the main console UI thread, CPU usage goes way down, but the application becomes unresponsive with a 2 second delay.

Comment: Try `Thread.Sleep(10);` The application will feel responsive but you won't hog the CPU. Another approach to the task would be to have a field bool `_stopRequested` andto set it to true when the user asks to stop, and within the `workerThread` you check if you must stop every loop cycle and all around.

Comment: That does work. I was wondering if there are any methodological ways that I can restructure this code so that the main thread will halt indefinitely until a key-press event occurs?

Comment: Updated my comment already. Add to that a simple `ReadLine()` in the main and its exactly what you're describing.

Comment: `ReadKey()` is also blocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really have to constantly poll for input?  If you are waiting for input in a separate thread, just use the Console.ReadKey.  It will block the input thread, but your other thread will keep processing.  You don't seem to be doing anything else on the input thread, so blocking shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: This is probably the answer that makes the most sense. Polling for input is generally a bad idea. Even though its not process intensive to continuously check for input, if you just set your process off on an endless loop its going to consume CPU time, and if your OS has nothing else to schedule your just going to be checking for input thousands of times a second. There are multiple concurrency models that you can implement here, but polling on another thread doesn't seem at all efficient.

Comment: Thank you, this answer is what I needed. I had a feeling that `Console.ReadKey` should be blocking. After your answer, I realized that my `if (Console.KeyAvailable)` was bypassing the `Console.ReadKey` and so the application was not acting as I expected until the if condition was removed.

Answer (score 0):

Look like your esc key press check logic running in end less loop due to while loop. Due to this the function keep utilizing the system resource.

To overcome this please use some delay in your loop using Thread.Sleep.  1 second delay will improve  lot of performance.

Comment: This feels like some pharmacy product commercial.

Comment: Dont put sleep on your main thread it keep the application hang as you rightly pointed out